# Companion's Insight not working

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, skyrim-dragonborn

The Black Book ability, *Companion's Insight* doesn't work. I can still kill my companions with daggers and all. I heard area spells bypass this ability but nothing changes, they can be hurt anyways. How to solve this?

Comment: Can you clarify whether your area effect spells damage your followers or not? That's the only thing that *should* be affected, and it works for my character. Weapons, including things like Dawnbreaker's burst, should still harm allies, and friendly NPCs aren't protected.

Comment: Companion's insight is not suppose to stop dagger damage.

Comment: Area effect spells too. Dawnbreaker hurts everytime no matter what anyways, doesn't it?